# Why are choliambics not included in the musisque deoque database?

Tags: poetry

It seems like the musisque deoque have literally scanned all of Latin poetry and maybe even Greek but I haven't search that.  Here is a list of the meters found in their database:

http://mizar.unive.it/mqdq/public/indici/metri/metro/V

But the first half of the first poem in the Satyricon is a choliambic and it is not included in the database why?

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be grouping choliambics under iambics, of which they are a modification. The Satyricon poem is listed in that category: http://mizar.unive.it/mqdq/public/testo/testo/ordinata/pf990108.